# how to configure firebase react-native ignite "better practice"

Tags: react-native

How could set the firebase to infinitered/ignite the best way?

I'm starting now and have several doubts however I think you should add a FirebaseConfig.js in the / Config. Right?
My file FirebaseConfig.js now.

```
import Config from 'react-native-config'**
const firebase = require ( 'firebase');
// Initialize Firebase

import Config from 'react-native-config'

const firebase = require('firebase');

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: Config.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: Config.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: Config.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    storageBucket: Config.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: Config.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```